# Chrome PopUp Windows limitation

Tags: windows, google-chrome, popup

We have built an app for stock charts with aspx running on a browser.  When we open 4 stock charts as separate popup windows, runs great under Chrome.  When we add the 5th popup window, Chrome shows a white flash as it updates the chart.  Remove the 5th popup chart window and the white flash goes away.  This does not occur under Firefox or IE, just Chrome.  If we open the charts in tabs instead of popup windows, the white flash does not occur.

Is there some limitation on the number of open popup windows in Chrome and can we get around the limitation somehow?

Comment: Given the nature of the problem it would help to know what kind of computer, which version of Windows and whether this has been tried on multiple computers.

Comment: this was tried on xp, vista, and win7, laptops and desktops, intel chipset and amd chipset, tried on about 7 computers.  all have the exact same result.  up to 4 popup windows--its fine.  add the 5th and get white flash everytime the chart updates.  renders the chart unusable.  remove the 5th chart and the 4 charts work fine again.